# Service Stack customize AutoQuery

Tags: servicestack

We are using Service Stack in our project with great success and have a need to filter the results coming back from AutoQuery to those records we have marked as being not deleted. We soft delete data by turning on an IsDeleted bit field in our tables, and currently AutoQuery is pulling back those deleted records.

Thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [AutoQuery Extensibility with QueryFilters](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#extensibility-with-queryfilters) where you can apply additional conditions using a QueryFilter:

```
var autoQuery = new AutoQueryFeature()
  .RegisterQueryFilter<QueryRockstarsFilter, Rockstar>((q, dto, req) =>
      q.And(x => x.LastName.EndsWith("son"))
  )
  .RegisterQueryFilter<IFilterRockstars, Rockstar>((q, dto, req) =>
      q.And(x => x.LastName.EndsWith("son"))
  );

Plugins.Add(autoQuery);
```